# Construct R1C1 to use in worksheet function

Tags: excel, vba

I used "RowNKC" for the row to R1C1 Formula but it's in excel function

```
Dim RowNKC As Integer    
RowNKC = Range("CuoiNKC").Row - 1   
Dim RowCDPS As Integer   
RowCDPS = Range("CuoiCDPS").Row - 1    
Dim i As Integer    
For i = 9 To RowCDPS
    If Cells(i, 9).Formula = Space(0) Then
       Cells(i, 7).Formula = "=SUMIF(**"NKC!R9C12:R" & RowNKC & "C12"**,CDPS!RC[-6],NKC!R9C15:R1189C15)"
```

Comment: How are `Range("CuoiNKC")` and `Range("CuoiCDPS")` defined? What do they refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.FormulaR1C1` when assigning a formula in R1C1 syntax. Optionally, just check if there is a formula in column I rather than compare it to a zero length string. Assuming that `Range("CuoiNKC")` and `Range("CuoiCDPS")` are defined names referring to a single cell each the following should get you started.

```
Dim i As Long, RowNKC As Long, RowCDPS As Long
With ActiveSheet
    RowNKC = Range("CuoiNKC").Row - 1
    RowCDPS = Range("CuoiCDPS").Row - 1
    For i = 9 To RowCDPS
        If Not .Cells(i, 9).HasFormula Then
           .Cells(i, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "'=SUMIF(NKC!R9C12:R" & RowNKC & "C12 , CDPS!RC[-6], NKC!R9C15:R1189C15)"
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

I don't think that formula is actually going to work as the [SUMIF function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx) needs to have the same number of rows in the *sum_range* as the *criteria range*.

Comment: Where's is like button, I wanna say thank you Jeeped

Comment: @kobebryant - Click the checkmark to accept this as your answer. Helpful votes are added/removed with the up/down arrows just above the checkmark.